# Proper AutoresizingMask

Tags: ios, uiview, uiinterfaceorientation, autoresizingmask

I have a view that appears at the center of its parent view portrait mode, what autoresizemask should I use so that it appears in the center in landscape mode too. It's size should remain same.I just want its origin should shift themselves automatically at the point so that it appears at the center.Any help please?

I have given

```
[parentView setAutoResizesSubview:YES];

parentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
// horizontal
childView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;

// vertical
childView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;

// both
childView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
```

Answer (score 3):

Swift 3:

```
childView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

childView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleTopMargin, .flexibleBottomMargin, .flexibleLeftMargin, .flexibleRightMargin]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If you are using swift:
// horizontal
childView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleLeftMargin, .flexibleRightMargin]
// vertical
childView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleTopMargin, .flexibleBottomMargin]
// both
childView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleLeftMargin, .flexibleRightMargin, .flexibleTopMargin, .flexibleBottomMargin]
```